# Is this integration question correctly answered?

Tags: integration, chain-rule

So we have:

$$y = (x^3 + 2)^7$$

And we want to find:

$$I = \int y \space dx \\$$

From the chain rule, we know:

$${d\over dx} g \Big( f(x) \Big) = g' \Big( f(x) \Big) \cdot f'(x)$$

Hence:

$$\int g' \Big( f(x) \Big) \cdot f'(x) \space dx =  g \Big( f(x) \Big) \\ $$

Let's call this identity $(1)$ so we don't have to rewrite it.

So I looked at  $\space (x^3 + 2)^8 $. Which differentiates to give:

$${24x^2} (x^3 + 2)^7$$

So if we integrate this we get:

$$8 \int {3x^2} (x^3 + 2)^7 \space dx= (x^3 + 2)^8 $$

(Note I took $8$ out the integral).

Now we divide by $8$ and get:

$$\int {3x^2} (x^3 + 2)^7 \space dx= {(x^3 + 2)^8 \over 8}$$

The integral on the left is in the same format as the identity $(1)$.

Does this mean that:

$$I = {(x^3 + 2)^8 \over 8} + C$$

Or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Try differentiating. Your solution is not correct.

Comment: You wanted $\int (x^3+2)^7\operatorname d x$ not $\int 3x^2(x^3+2)^7\operatorname d x$.  They are not the same thing at all.

Comment: Instead of "(1)", let's call this identity the "Chain Rule" because that's what everyone does for derivatives, or "u-substitution" because that's what everyone does for integration.  Using standard terminology *improves* your writing.

Comment: @EricTowers - I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply binomial theorem to integrate $(x^3+2)^7$ directly:
\begin{align}
\int (x^3+2)^7 dx &= \int \left(\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{7}{k} 2^{7-k}x^{3k}\right) dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^7 \binom{7}{k}\frac{2^{7-k}}{3k+1}x^{3k+1}+C
\end{align}

Comment: Oh my goodness... that never crossed my mind!!!  Makes it MUCH easier. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're a genius... again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You have computed the antiderivative of $3x^2 (x^3 + 2)^7$.  Why do you think this informs you about the antiderivative of $(x^3+2)^7$, which is a different function?

Comment: I'm not too sure. I really didn't think when I wrote the question, I'm really tired... I'll delete it and figure it out on my own.

Comment: @MaxEchendu : What was your *actual* question?  You asked if your method here was correct and are told that it is not.  You still seem to have a question.  Why have you not asked the question you actually have?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I figured it was incorrect minutes after posting it. I was looking for help on evaluating such an integral.